# Suggestion on how to deal with different user right

Tags: codeigniter, version-control, logic

I have a page which have different version, one is member, one is admin, and one is guest. 
You may know what is the different, if the user, they have:
login button
register button

if the user is a member, they have:
logout button
edit button in they content

and the admin, will have:
logout button
banned button for all content

So, my question is, they are similar content, show I make 3 separate page? or one page to do all this stuff? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use one page and use ACL to define what every user can do. I heard ZEND_Acl is a good start.

Definition of ACL:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Access_control_list

CodeIgniter + Zend ACL:

http://www.lucdebrouwer.nl/adding-zend-acl-to-codeigniter/

http://www.revolves.net/2008/12/18/using-zend-acl-with-codeigniter/